# Flask relationships with sql alschemy - no such table error

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm working through a flask relationships tutorial. I'm trying to make a database that stores puppies, information about their toys, and information about their owners, showing in
basic.py:

```
# basic.py
import os
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate 

basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///'+os.path.join(basedir, 'data.sqlite')
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
Migrate(app, db)

class Puppy(db.Model):
     
    __tablename__ = 'puppies'
    
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    name = db.Column(db.Text)
    toys = db.relationship('Toy', backref = 'puppy', lazy = 'dynamic')
    owner = db.relationship('Owner', backref = 'puppy', uselist = False)
    
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        
    def __repr__(self):
        if self.owner:
            return "Puppy name is {self.name} and owner is {self.owner}"
        else:
            return "Puppy is {self.name} and has no owner yet"
        
    def report_toys(self):
        print("Here are my toys:")
        for toy in self.toys:
            print(toy.item_name)
    
class Toy(db.Model):
    
    __tablename__ = 'toys'
    
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    item_name = db.Column(db.Text)
    puppy_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('puppies.id'))
    
    def __init__(self, item_name, puppy_id):
        self.item_name = item_name
        self.puppy_id = puppy_id
        
class Owner(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'owners'
    
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    name = db.Column(db.Text)
    puppy_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('puppies.id'))
    
    def __init__(self, name, puppy_id):
        self.name = name
        self.puppy_id = puppy_id
```

I then set up a manual database in models.py:

```
# models.py
from basic import db, Puppy, Owner, Toy

rufus = Puppy('Rufus')

fido = Puppy('Fido')

db.session.add_all([rufus, fido])
db.session.commit

rufus = Puppy.query.filter_by(name = 'Rufus').first()

kate = Owner('Kate', rufus.id)

toy1 = Toy('Chew Toy', rufus.id)
toy2 = Toy('Ball', rufus.id)

db.session.add_all([kate, toy1, toy2])
db.session.commit()
```

But I'm getting an error:

```
cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (raised as a result of Query-invoked autoflush; consider using a session.no_autoflush block if this flush is occurring prematurely)
(sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: puppies
[SQL: INSERT INTO puppies (name) VALUES (?)]
[parameters: ('Rufus',)]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/e3q8)
```

I'm new to this, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you create the database ?

you need to import your db object and models and then create the database like following:

```
(venv) $ flask shell
>>> from basic import db
>>> from basic import Puppy, Toy, Owner
>>> db.create_all()
```

let me know if this solves your problem

Answer (score 2):

The error message shows no table of puppies in your database. To apply migrations to your database, you need some steps while using flask-migrate.

The link would be helpful https://flask-migrate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using flask_migrate you need to open a terminal, be sure to be in the same working directory of your project and run these commands:

This you need to run it before you run the actual Flask App

> 1. CMD with in the envirorments folder:

```
>>> set FLASK_APP= app.py (optional)
>>> flask db init
>>> flask db migrate -m 'Any name you want'  ---> what's inside the '' is the name of migrati
>>> flask db upgrade  (perform the actual migration)
```

> Normally if you don't use flask_migrate but only flask_sqlalchemy or SQLAlchemy vanilla, this is what you should run.

1. CMD with in the envirorments folder:

```
>>> from app import db
>>> db.create_all()
>>> exit() #or ctrl + z then enter
```

> > > EDIT

Everytime you are adding something (or removing) from the DB Tables of instance:

```
class Puppy(db.Model):
     
    __tablename__ = 'puppies'
    
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    name = db.Column(db.Text)
    toys = db.relationship('Toy', backref = 'puppy', lazy = 'dynamic')
    owner = db.relationship('Owner', backref = 'puppy', uselist = False)
```

Becomes --->

```
class Puppy(db.Model):
     
    __tablename__ = 'puppies'
    
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    name = db.Column(db.Text)
    age = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)#Added new item
    toys = db.relationship('Toy', backref = 'puppy', lazy = 'dynamic')
    owner = db.relationship('Owner', backref = 'puppy', uselist = False)
```

Then you should delete the database file, in your case  'data.sqlite' (within your working directory) and run the above mentioned code again,

### In fact by running the above code, you create database table but also the actual sqlite file